# Explain this bash script: echo "${1##*.}"

Tags: bash

Consider the following bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "${1##*.}"
```

This script prints the extension of a file if the file name is supplied as the first command line argument, something like following:

```
$ ./script.sh ./file.pdf
```

In the above case `pdf` is printed.

Please explain how the expression `${1##*.}` is able to extract the extension of the file.

(I understand what $0, $1, $2, $# do in bash and also understand about regular expressions to some extent)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Bash parameter expansion supports several modifications it can do to the value while expanding a variable. [One of them is `##`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion), which removes the longest prefix of the value [matching a pattern](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching) (patterns are *not* regular expressions here).

In this case the pattern is `*.`. That matches any zero or more characters followed by a `.`. `${x##*.}` means to remove all of the string up to the last `.` character, and leave everything after that dot.

`${1##*.}` means to do that expansion using the value of the first positional parameter, the one you'd usually access with `$1`. The final result of

```
echo "${1##*.}"
```

is then to print out the part of the first argument of the script that comes after the last `.`, which is the filename extension.

If the pattern **doesn't** match at all, the full value of the variable is expanded, just as if you hadn't used the `##`. In this case, if the argument you gave didn't have a `.` in it at all then you'd just get it back out again.

Bash also supports a single `#` to take the shortest matching prefix off, and the same thing with `%` to match the end of the string instead.

Comment: Wonderful answer. Clear as a bell, and I have learned something new which should be helpful in my bash scripts.

Comment: @mikeserv: Fair point on non-matching expansion (edited). This is explicitly a Bash question, though, so I'm not going to go all POSIX on it this time.

Comment: and fair enough about not going all POSIXy. I just thought something like *`bash` supported parameter expansion* as opposed to *`bash` parameter expansion* would be nearer the mark.

Answer (score 9):

Simple example:

```
$ A=my.file.name.txt

$ echo ${A}
my.file.name.txt

$ echo ${A#m}
y.file.name.txt

$ echo ${A#my}
.file.name.txt

$ echo ${A#*.}
file.name.txt

$ echo ${A##*.}
txt
```

In a script, ${1} is the first argument, and the same concept applies.

Comment: this answer is a perfect complement to the first voted, simple and clear, in 5 lines teaches a lot!

Answer (score 7):

Note Bash parameter expansion :

You can trim a string from the head by using # operator

You can trim a string from the tail by using % operator

lets take an example :

```
[my->prompt]$ VAR="head:string:tail"
[my->prompt]$ echo ${VAR##*:}               //trim from the head -> till the last ':'
tail
[my->prompt]$ echo ${VAR#*:}                //trim from the head -> till the first ':' 
string:tail
[my->prompt]$ echo ${VAR%%:*}               //trim from the tail <- till the last ':'
head
[my->prompt]$ echo ${VAR%:*}                //trim from the tail <- till the first ':'
head:string
[my->prompt]$ VAR2=${VAR%:*}                //VAR2="head:string"
[my->prompt]$ echo $VAR2
head:string
[my->prompt]$ echo ${VAR2#*:}               //trim from the head -> till the first ':' 
string
```

Comment: Hey - whose prompt is that?!?

Comment: Hey!!! its mine but after changing the original prompt message :)